# How to update final associated record

Tags: mysql

I have list of `items` that are belongs to `orders`. Each `item` has `fee_percentage` field. and the sum of `items` is `total_price` in `orders` table.

What I want to achieve? 
I want to update the `fee` field of last associated items.

```
_________________________      __________________________________________
| order ID | total_price|      | id | order_id | fee_percentage |  fee  |
-------------------------      ------------------------------------------
|   334    |     425    |      |  1 |   334    |      50        |  212  |
  # The `fee` should be 213 => |  2 |   334    |      50        |  212  |
```

As you can see the sum of `items` will be 424. I want to add the remaining fee to the last item `fee`. (So the fee of item id 2 should be 213).

Any help please?

This is what I have written so far

```
UPDATE items AS i
LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.order_id = b.order_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT order_id, SUM(fee) AS sum_fee
    FROM items 
    GROUP BY order_id
    WHERE deleted = 0
) AS b1 ON b1.order_id = b.order_id
SET b.fee = b.fee + (o.total_price - b1.sum_fee)
WHERE b.deleted = 0;
```

Comment: are you using integers to store imports?

Comment: Yes. I am using integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it here: http://rextester.com/MGKS16637

I'm getting `max(Id)` and difference between `sum(fee)` and total price from `items` table. If this value is <> 0, then update the item with `id=max(id)`.

```
update items
       join (select max(i.id) mid, o.totalPrice - sum(i.fee) as diff
           from items i
           inner join orders o on i.order_Id = o.orderId
           group by i.order_id
           order by i.order_id, i.id) v
       on items.id = v.mid
set items.fee = items.fee + v.diff
where v.diff <> 0;
```